# Were early US citizens ever able to get reparations for the Revolutionary War?

Tags: american-revolution

In looking into the aftermath of the American Revolutionary War I ran across a list of citizens applying for reparations to the new government:

[Reparation Requests](https://www.chester.pa-roots.com/military/revolutionarywar/reparationrequests.html)

The state of New Jersey even provides a database of claims:

[Revolutionary War Damage Claims](https://wwwnet-dos.state.nj.us/DOS_ArchivesDBPortal/RevWarDamages.aspx)

I had run across sources which say a number of people who helped fund the war, including some of the original founders went bankrupt in the aftermath. Did the US Government ever get around to honoring any of those claims either before or after the creation of the constitution? Was there any successful legal recourse for the patriots affected?

Comment: I can find no evidence for the affirmative, but this is one of those questions where it may be very hard to prove the negative.

Comment: @BrianZ Thanks for the assist. I am researching some of the legal proceedings of that time.